# Server side validation using validation controls

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a form with the following controls

1. textbox for emailId -txtEmail
2. textbox for aboutme- txtAbout
3. submit button -btnSubmit

I'm using requiredfieldvalidators and reqularexpression validators for both the text fields.
I need to do  serverside validations. So I've set EnableClientScript to false.

txtAbout and btnSubmit should be disabled if txtEmail is either empty or invalid.  How do I fire the validation for this?

Also, if I'm asked to do Server Side validation, should I EnableClientScript to false, 'coz I read somewhere that even if is set to true, server side validation will fire.

Answer (score 0):

> txtAbout and btnSubmit should be disabled if txtEmail is either empty
>   or invalid. How do I fire the validation for this?

In order to implement this, according to my understanding you need to do client side validation. At client side you can use `key press/Up events` and you can use `regular expressions i.e. RegExp` in the `javascript` to validate the Email address textbox...and the corresponding underneath controls can be `Enabled/Disabled` on the basis of Email validation.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your reply.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a customvalidator to check the email format using Regex.Match .  But for onservervalidate of the customvalidator fires only on btnSubmit click.  so how can I get the onservervalidate to fire without clicking on btnSubmit?  Thanks your response is appreciated.

Comment: write the code in a common function and call it on button click as well as on validating the email at textbox key press/Up events...